# To use 'QUERY_STRING' or 'REQUEST_URI'

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have researched high and low but yet to find what I'm looking for.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^shop$
RewriteRule ^shop/(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What i want to happen is the following:

1. Check incoming URL for value 'shop'
2. If value 'shop' is found run the rewriterule

Right now, its not being run because the condition is not being met.
When i take the RewriteCond away, it correctly removes the 'shop' from the URL but then enters an infinite loop.

I've tried using the REQUEST_URI and QUERY_STRING variables but neither seem to be working.

Am currently using WooCommerce for the shop

Full product URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/shop/category/product/
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is full shop URL and where do you want it to redirect to?

Comment: Do you want `/shop/category/product/` be redirected to `/category/product/`?

Comment: When you get 404 what URL is shown in browser?

Comment: Sorry i deleted my reply. Will respond in block below.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPres
```

Comment: Ok, I tried the rules above and It's still entering a redirect loop. :(

Comment: It went to a 404 page the first time I went to a product page. However the shop was removed from the URL.

Comment: Did you not want `/shop/category/product/` be redirected to `/category/product/` ? Test this in a browser

Comment: The RewriteRule is working however it still enters a redirect loop.

Comment: There is no looping caused by these rules. However if your WP code/plugin is forcing `/shop` in the URL then it will loop.